# Unable to Connect to Rabbit MQ

Tags: .net-core, rabbitmq, amqp

I am using amazon service and created rabbitmq broker now from the DOT NET code i am trying to connect to this broker.

```
   var factory = new ConnectionFactory
   {
      Uri = new Uri("amqps://it:Password@hostname:5671")
   };

    var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
```

I am struggle here to get connection getting below error :

```
  None of the specified endpoints were reachable

   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(IEndpointResolver endpointResolver, String clientProvidedName)
```

Comment: Can you telnet to server port 5671 from your client system?

Comment: @mjn [ec2-user@ip-x-x-x-x ~]$ telnet host 5671
Trying host...
Connected to host.amazonaws.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.  It's getting connected but after some time getting message connection closed by client

Comment: Sorry I only found this guide related to AWS for a Java client, but maybe it contains some useful information about prerequisites: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/latest/developer-guide/getting-started-rabbitmq.html

Comment: @mjn tried everything not sure what is the problem .

Comment: Try to set the credentials on the factory instead in the URL. The example in the linked guide shows how to set them. Maybe passing them in the URI is not supported.

Comment: @mjn did all combination and permutation :)

Answer (score 0):

Update:

It seems your client wants to connect using TLS/SSL (your uri specifies the protocol "amqps" and the port 5671).

Try enabling TLS/SSL:

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory { 
UserName = userName, 
Password = password, 
VirtualHost = "/", 
HostName = hostName, 
Port = port, 
Ssl = new SslOption 
  { Enabled = true, // <--------
    ServerName = hostName } 
};
```

---

The (JVM based) [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/latest/developer-guide/getting-started-rabbitmq.html) shows how to configure the connection factory. It sets the credentials on the factory, not in the URI:

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();

factory.setUsername(username); // <----------
factory.setPassword(password); // <----------

//Replace the URL with your information
factory.setHost("b-c8352341-ec91-4a78-ad9c-a43f23d325bb.mq.us-west-2.amazonaws.com");
factory.setPort(5671);

// Allows client to establish a connection over TLS
factory.useSslProtocol()

// Create a connection
Connection conn = factory.newConnection();
```

(This needs to be translated to the corresponding .NET code)

Comment: this for for java based code equivalent to this in .NET i tried

Comment: var factory = new ConnectionFactory
                    {
                        UserName = userName,
                        Password = password,
                        VirtualHost = "/",
                        HostName = hostName,
                        Port = port,
                        Ssl = new SslOption
                        {
                            Enabled = false,
                            ServerName = hostName
                        }
                    };

Comment: Try Ssl = new SslOption { Enabled = true, ..